# WP Install: Event registration - registered by participant id

Tags: civievent, registration

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious and hope someone can point me to the answer.

We had an event where people could purchase a ticket for themselves and guests (up to 3). That's all good. The thing is, I can't figure out how to run a report which shows the purchaser and who their guest/s is/are. I HAVE figured out how to see the "registered by participant ID" # (see below), but I'd love to see the name of the participant who registered the guest and I can't figure that out. I'd like to be able to see a report which shows the Registrant --> Guest(s)

[image]

It's possible I set this up incorrectly from the get-go - I'm a Civi newbie - but I appreciate any guidance anyone can offer!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party here, I know - but we ended up writing code to extend the report to add a "Registered by Contact Name" column to the output here.

Happy to share this code if it's still useful.

Best
Marcus

Comment: share away - perhaps do as a PR to the Extended Report extension and perhaps Eileen or someone at Fuzion will check and add

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you need to know the **"Registered by Participant ID"**

I guess you know to find the report from the following path (menu)

Reports => Event Reports => Attendee List OR Event Participants List

In both the reports you do have a option displaying **"columns"**

just select **"Registered by Participant ID"** which should display

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Hi, Ramesh. I was able to construct that report (that's the image), but I can't figure out how to display the name associated with the "Registered by Participant ID." I looked for an extension that could do the job, but didn't find one. It might mean a custom report is needed or something like that.

Comment: Yeah in this case you might have to use excel and a vlookup :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal then I would look in to building a Drupal View to deliver the required information - not having tried for this particular outcome therefore flagging that it may require views_field_view so that you can use that id as a Contextual filter in a related view to get that Contact's name etc